# read weighing scale data via RS232 to USB cable in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to read data from **weighing scale YH-T7E** using raspberry pi via RS232 to USB cable in pyhon. However, when I am reading the data via it gives me empty string.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',
                    baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, 
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
                    timeout = 1)

while True:
    print(ser.read())
```

The output of above code is:

```
b''
```

I have also tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053983/pyserial-prints-empty-b-from-a-usb-serial-port) post but it gives nothing since it keeps on waiting:

```
while True:
    data = ''
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    data += ser.read()
    if data:
        print("Received: ", data)
```

I have verified RS232 is properly connected with the laptop:

```
[ 6105.752153] usb 1-1.2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Even when I used minicom, configured baud rate and other parameters, still no data received.

Here is the [YH-T7E manual](http://www.scale-israel.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/T7E.pdf) for the reference

Kindly assist me?

Comment: As the scale simply sends data you should first test that you are receiving and using the correct baud rate by using a serial terminal program. Or PySerial has a terminal mode - look at the documentation. Once that is showing the data from the scale, you can try to get your code working. BTW the manual mentions nothing about the data having even parity, and specifies that data is 8-bit. Plus it’s not clear what the default baud rate is so you need to assert that in the scale calibration settings.

Comment: Plus there’s the confusing ‘large screen’ section in the manual which talks about current loop, which is a different electrical interface than RS232. Maybe that’s what the in/out pins on the RS232 connector diagram are about, in which case you can ignore that.

Comment: I have seen somewhere else that parity is None. Also, I have calibrated the device, its baud rate is 1200

Comment: Did you try a serial terminal? Or does your code run better with the correct settings?

Comment: I tried minicom, calibrated the scale, set the baud rate to 9600 but still no luck :(

Comment: Are you sure your code is connecting to the correct port? Did you try PySerial’s terminal mode?

Comment: I didn't treid pySerial terminal mode. But I tried minicom (serial port communication program)

Comment: The reason using pyserial terminal mode is that this is python code which you can examine to see what settings it makes when successfully receiving data from your scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The call to `ser.read()` would read one byte at the time - so you should see one character per line if it receives any data. You should probably troubleshoot a bit here.

- Are you wires connected correctly? Is the TX from the scale connected to the RX on your RS232 port? Are the grounds connected together?
- Are the communication settings correct? Have you tried to set it to 8 bits instead? Also try to set parity to ODD or EVEN, maybe NONE also?
- Does you USB RS232 work? Maybe you could check it on some other device?

Comment: I have verified USB connection is fine, [ 2440.370289] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-Ser!
[ 2440.371011] ch341 1-1.2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 2440.374064] usb 1-1.2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1

Comment: That sounds good. I was more thinking of the hardware side of the USB serial device. For example some cheap devices I've bought of Ebay do not adhere to the voltage levels os RS232. If you have some other device that can output RS232 you could test that it works.

Comment: unfortunately, I have no other device to test

Comment: If you can receive using minicom then the USB adapter is working, so it comes back to your code. Is your code opening ttyusb1 which you indicate is used in a comment above?

Comment: @J.P.Petersen , the weighing scale wires were not connected properly. Fixed that, and the data was coming up perfectly

Comment: Good to hear :) and happy new year.