# Pyserial readline returns empty b'' with STM32F437

Tags: stm32, pyserial

The issue is similar to another question from 7 years ago that was never solved: [Pyserial prints empty b ' ' from a USB serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053983/pyserial-prints-empty-b-from-a-usb-serial-port)

Here, I'm using the simple code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600,timeout=1)

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(ser.readline())
```

This code works fine when reading an Arduino. It also works on MacOS. But when I try to read data from the STM32F437 microcontroller on my Windows laptop, I keep getting b'' printed every second, instead of encoded values between the quotation marks.

Comment: What is the STM32 sending? Have you verified using a terminal emulator or similar?